# 3-dimensional array reshaping? HDF5 dataset type?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, reshape, numpy-ndarray, hdf5

I have data in the following **shape: (127260, 2, 1250)**

The type of this data is `<HDF5 dataset "data": shape (127260, 2, 1250), type "<f8">`

The first dimension (127260) is the number of signals, the second dimension (2) is the type of signal, and the third dimension (1250) is the amount of points in each of the signals.

What I wanted to do is **reduce the amount of points for each signal, cut them in half, leave 625 points on each signal, and then have double the amount of signals**.

How to convert HDF5 dataset to something like numpy array and how to do this reshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want a new dataset with shape: `(2*127260, 2, 625)`. If so, it's fairly simple to read 2 slices of the dataset into 2 NumPy arrays, create a new array from the slices, then write to a new dataset. Note: reading slices is simple and fast. I would leave the data as-is and do this on-the-fly unless you have a compelling reason to create a new dataset

Code to do this (where `h5f` is the h5py file object):

```
new_arr = np.empty((2*127260, 2, 625))
arr1 = h5f['dataset_name'][:,:, :625]
arr2 = h5f['dataset_name'][:,:,  625:]
new_arr[:127260,:,:] = arr1 
new_arr[127260:,:,:] = arr2 
h5f.create_dataset('new_dataset_name',data=new_arr)
```

Alternately you can do this (and combine 2 steps):

```
new_arr = np.empty((2*127260, 2, 625))
new_arr[:127260,:,:] = h5f['dataset_name'][:,:, :625]
new_arr[127260:,:,:] = h5f['dataset_name'][:,:,  625:]
h5f.create_dataset('new_dataset_name',data=new_arr)
```

Here is a 3rd method. It is the most direct way, and reduces the memory overhead. This is important when you have very large datasets that won't fit in memory.

```
h5f.create_dataset('new_dataset_name',shape=(2*127260, 2, 625),dtype=float)
h5f['new_dataset_name'][:127260,:,:] = h5f['dataset_name'][:,:, :625]
h5f['new_dataset_name'][127260:,:,:] = h5f['dataset_name'][:,:,  625:]
```

Whichever method you choose, I suggest adding an attribute to note the data source for future reference:

```
h5f['new_dataset_name'].attrs['Data Source'] = 'data sliced from dataset_name'
```

Comment: It worked, that was it, it helped me a lot, thank you very much. I was going to comment on adding one more parentheses in np.empty and replacing parentheses with square brackets in new_arr, but I saw that you already edited and fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I posted that without checking my code. :-(  BTW, there is a 3rd way to slice the data and write directly to a new dataset (without creating the intermediate array: `new_arr`). That reduces the memory overhead when you have really large datasets. I will add to the answer for future reference.